# Interior and Exterior lights randomly come on

Tags: chevrolet

I have a 2012 Chevy Cruze and sometimes the interior dome lights and the exterior headlights come on by themselves. I think it only happens at night but that could just be cause it's easier to see. Also the radio is suppose to play until you open the door with the keys out and sometimes it flickers on and off a few times. Any ideas?

Comment: Some cars activate the headlights for a short time when you open the door. Does this model have that feature?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like the body control module is going bad (or is bad). I believe GM uses the BCM for all of the functions you mentioned in newer vehicles.

Comment: Had one that th interior light would come on when a person of a certain mass sat in the passenger seat - broken spring shorting a wire...

Answer (score 3):

You may simply have a faulty door switch that is turning on and off when it shouldn’t.

Check that all the doors make the interior lights come on and go off when you open and close the doors.  You may also what to check the tailgate/trunk.

If one of them is not operating correctly then it’s switch may need replacing.

Comment: This was my first reaction. If the headlights are programmed to turn on when the door is opened or closed, one common denominator is a door switch. Another common denominator is the BCM. I'd start with checking the door switches.

Comment: The headlights do not come on when opening the door and today when I turned the car off and took the key out it was trying to start on it's own.